# ADF Dates Validation From Date to Date

Tags: validation, date, oracle-adf

[image]

I have two Input Dates Drag and Dropped from the Component Platte, so my requirement is

1. validation for " To Date Should not be less than From Date "
2. Only one month can apply on Dates (i.e if I enter 05-Jul-2017 in From Date then in to date not allowed to submit Aug Dates. Only July months Date we have to Apply.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can build this at the model layer (ADF Business components) as a row level validation - then add a partial trigger between the field to invoke the validation.